# PHPStorm IDE error with this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery, phpstorm

I took this snippet from the Colorbox site, yet when I load it into PHPStorm IDE it tells me that it is expecting either a "," or a ")" behind "rel:'group1'}"

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('a.photos').colorbox({ opacity:0.5 , rel:'group1'});
});
```

I'm new to Jquery so what gives - the code runs fine.

Many thanks !

Comment: Try wrapping opacity and rel in quotes

Comment: @mplungjan: not necessary. JS object keys only need to be quoted if they contain invalid characters, e.g. `{foo-bar:'baz'}` wouldn't work, but `{'foo-bar':'baz'}` would.

Comment: @mplungjan: Quotes are not needed.  That javascript is perfectly valid.  It is PHPStorm that is at fault, or there is more to the example then you are showing.

Comment: This is a IDE error, does the code actually work, and if it does, ignore the IDE.

Comment: code looks fine. That I would expect you to be confident about

Comment: PHPStorm7 doesn't complain about that snippet.

Comment: Quotes are not mandatory but might annoy the IDE

Comment: Please try `File | Invalidate caches...` and restart IDE.